# each function not executing removing inactive image

Tags: jquery

I use an each function to check whether an external image in a figure tag is 'alive' if not it should remove the figure container altogether, otherwise it should append the img as background and remove the image tag itself. In general the last task is done correctly but not the removing part when the image is not alive

```
$("figure img").each(function () {
    $(this).error(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});

$("figure img").each(function () {
    var source = $(this).attr("src");
    $(this).closest("figure").css("background-image", "url(" + source + ")");
    $(this).remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/skiweather/sL3hhhct/

Comment: problem two each function is a bit redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.error()` is deprecated, so you shouldn't use it. Use `.on("error")` instead.

The problem with your code is that `.error()` is an event handler, so it runs asynchronously. But your second `.each()` runs synchronously, so it will remove all the images before the `.error()` code is called. You should put that block in a handler for the `load` event, so it will run when the images load successfully.

You also don't need to use `.each()` when binding event handlers. You can bind the handler to the collection directly.

```
$("figure img").on({
    load: function() {
        var source = $(this).attr("src");
        $(this).closest("figure").css("background-image", "url(" + source + ")");
        $(this).remove();
    },
    error: function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/sL3hhhct/5/)

Comment: the image is not attached as background. The first image in the fiddle is the one which should be removed with it's parent (figure).

Comment: It works in my fiddle. You need to run the code in the `document.ready()` handler, not `window.onload`, because `onload` runs after everything has loaded, and the errors have already happened.

Answer (score 0):

This is all about timing. Your code will work if run in response to the appropriate browser events (notice the plural).

- document ready: attach error handlers to img elements
- document loaded: set bg images etc

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("figure img").each(function () {
        $(this).on('error', function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    });
});

$(document).load(function() {
    $("figure img").each(function () {
        var source = $(this).attr("src");
        $(this).closest("figure").css("background-image", "url(" + source + ")");
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sL3hhhct/6/)**

*Note that the fiddle is set up with "no wrap in head" option*

But it's maybe clearer to set everything up under document ready, and attach both an 'error' and a 'load' handler to the images :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("figure img").each(function () {
        var $that = $(this);
        $that.on({
            'error': function() {
                $that.parent().remove();
            },
            'load': function() {
                var source = $that.attr("src");
                $that.closest("figure").css("background-image", "url(" + source + ")");
                $that.remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sL3hhhct/7/)**